# jQuery DataTables: How can I explicitly set the table instance name / table ID to use with state saving?

Tags: datatables, local-storage, turbolinks, session-storage

**Background:**

I'm using DataTables in conjunction with a JS library called "Turbolinks", which basically turns your application into a Single Page Application (SPA) without all the overhead of using a true client-side framework. It is extremely useful for Ruby on Rails application performance.

There's a couple of headaches it introduces though - one is compatibility with DataTables. I've got it working pretty well by basically destroying any DataTable on a Turbolinks navigation, and then re-initializing it on turbolinks page load again. This method works well and seems to be the all-around accepted answer as to the best practice to get DataTables to work with Turbolinks.

**Question:**

On of the last features / finishing touches I'm trying to add to some of my applications is DataTable state saving. The issue I'm facing is that every time a table is destroyed/re-initialized on a page navigation, the...I'm actually not quite sure what to call it, but it looks like from inspecting the settings object on the stateSaveCallback - it looks like its the `sInstance` and/or the `sTableId`:

```
DataTables_Table_0
```

Then the localStorage key gets set as:

```
DataTables_DataTables_Table_0_/current_path: "{data: data}"
```

where current_path is whatever path/page you're on.

Then when it get re-initialized upon returning to the page, it gets set as `DataTables_Table_1`, and so on and so forth - so the state never gets correctly loaded.

Is there a way to override that ID (or some way to set the name of it in the `stateSaveCallback` / `stateLoadCallback`) so that it doesn't increase the last '0', '1', etc at the end of it? That way when the table is re-initialized, it will pull the saved state from just `DataTables_Table/current_path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to simply give the table an ID! Then DataTables won't assign it its own ID with the incrementing number and the saveState option just works.

Also, the destroy/re-init actually causes the server to get hit twice in the case of an AJAX table.

The better way to do it is to disable the turbolinks cache for any index pages with datatables. If not, you'll end up doing two requests to the server when only one is needed.